# Detox Hung on Splash Screen for React Native App

Tags: react-native, detox

Trying to set up Detox for my react native app. It seems to hang on the splash screen. I've managed to run tests on a seperate app with no splash screen. On the splash screen app it simply hangs and it outputs :

```
detox[34248] ERROR: Error: Exceeded timeout of 30000ms while handling jest-circus "setup" event
detox[34248] INFO:  Scratch Test is assigned to undefined
```

I recognize that a showing of 'undefined' is incorrect.

I see reference for the 'waitFor' function but the links to the documentation all seem to be broken and I can't find a reference to it in the docs.

I'm trying to understand how to go about debugging this or if the splash screen is at all responsible for the hanging / error.

Answer (score 2):

Do you use the "react-native-splash-screen" library? That apparently has some issue working with Detox and once I removed that, I did not have the timeout error.

Comment: thanks for the reply. yes, that's the one i'm using. Do you have a link to anything detailing the bug or limitation??

Comment: [This](https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/400#issuecomment-361664276) is a mention of how it's something the library has to fix not Detox.
[This](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen/issues/494) is the issue created in the Splash Screen library that references a fix and the Detox conversation

Comment: That is just a terrible library. No idea why so many people keep using it, then blame Detox it doesn’t work.

Comment: @LeoNatan do you have an alternative preference for react native splash screens??

Comment: No, but someone mentioned https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash

Answer (score 1):

Another potential source of the hanging is an animation that runs in the background. Detox tries to synchronize correctly, but isn't always able to, per their docs: https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.Synchronization.md.

I found that by adding

```
  // to allow for less flaky detox tests
  console.disableYellowBox = true;
```

to my app.tsx I was able to remove some warnings that were interfering with Detox.

Comment: As far as I am aware, the yellow box doesn’t introduce animations? Is this a recent change?

Comment: I was not aware of that. All I can say is that once I disabled yellow box, the flakiness in my local tests went away. Of course now I'm having trouble with Circle CI, but that seemed to fix any hanging I had been experiencing.